# How to hide PDF file on my website from bots with reCaptcha?

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha, captcha

I'm currently trying to share a PDF document on my personal website.
When it's not a problem to do it I need to hide it from bots.
I tried to use google's Invisible reCAPTCHA but had some issues.
Web-crawlers can search through source code so inactive button doesn't work.
Do I need a special page to check if reCAPTCHA is done? Maybe is there an easy way to always show  link but hide link HREF or form ACTION attribute (maybe with PHP help) when non-human is found?

```
        <form id="resume" action="subpage_that_shows_my_pdf_file_link.html" method="POST">
            <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="666" data-callback="onSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Actually google docs are not helping with this.

Comment: " tried to use google's Invisible reCAPTCHA but had some issues." share the issues, share the code

Comment: issue is as I wrote - bots still can see the direct link in a source code

Comment: you are doing this wrong, page with reCAPTCHA posts to new page, new page checks reCAPTCHA and serves file.

Comment: ok, so bots still can acces that page and find a PDF link, how to prevent them?

Comment: by not puting the link on a page that cant be accessed untill you pass a reCAPTCHA test

Comment: I think you didn't understand, bots will go to that page without CLICK but only by viewing source code, it's shown in provided code

Comment: so the question is how to use PHP/AJAX/GOOGLE-CAPTCHA-SERVICE to hide real address (pdf or html, doesn't matter)

Comment: i understand fine. move the file location to a page that's only displayed after reCAPTCHA check

Comment: ok, you didn't really understood :) look one more time at the code (I changed it) - bots still can see it in source code, am I right? so, when bots goes to that page still can see download link

Comment: yes bots can see the source code, so what you want cant use the code above. your not understanding that what you have above cant work.

Comment: that's why I asked this question - how to get reCAPTCHA permission (propably in php) to show some code

Comment: I did it! let me show you a whole code in the next comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it with *captcha-response*. My main parts of code:

**index.php**

```
        <form id="reCaptchaForm" action="file.php" method="POST">
            <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..." data-callback='onSubmit' >link</button>
        </form>
```

**file.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
$secretKey = '...';
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$reCaptchaValidationUrl = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteIp");
$result = json_decode($reCaptchaValidationUrl, TRUE);
if($result['success'] == 1) {
    $userMessage = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='file.pdf'" />';
}
```

On special page code is displayed only if in this particular session google invisible captcha says *yes, looks like a normal user* :)